# Put the post-order traversal values in an arraylist

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

On the web there is the solution for printing the values, like this:

```
void printPostorder(Node node) 
{ 
    if (node == null) 
        return; 

    // first recur on left subtree 
    printPostorder(node.left); 

    // then recur on right subtree 
    printPostorder(node.right); 

    // now deal with the node 
    System.out.print(node.key + " "); 
}
```

But my problem is that I don't want to print the values but put them in an `ArrayList`. That part is easy I've tried to use `ArrayList.add` instead of `System.out.print`, but my struggle is that I want to return it so instead of `void` my return type will be `ArrayList`. The problem is that I don't know what to return in the base case:

```
if (node == null) 
        return;
```

My method does return an `ArrayList` so what can I return for the base case above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end case you could return an empty list, and accumulate the results by calling `addAll`:

```java
List<Node> getPostOrderList(Node node) { 
    List<Node> retVale = new ArrayList<>();
    if (node == null) {
        return retVal; 
    }

    // first recur on left subtree 
    retVal.addAll(getPostOrderList(node.left));

    // then recur on right subtree 
    retVal.addAll(getPostOrderList(node.right));

    // now deal with the node 
    retVal.add(node);

    return retVal;
}
```